# Questions regarding single and double quotes within a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, regex, validation

i have this javascript example that contains a regex allowing a single quote but, due to the single quote, there are problems:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checkname() {
        var name = document.getElementById('Name');
        var filter = ^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,50};
        if (!filter.test(name.value)) {
            alert('name is not valid');
            name.focus;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

#### Tests i made:

- if i add `single` or `double quotes` around the `"regex"` the regex doesn't work.
- if i add `forward slashes` around the `/regex/` then the regex works but not fully as for example it doesn't allow `100name` but it allows `name100`.
- if i add both double quotes and forward slashes `"/regex/"` or `'/regex/'` then the regex doesn't work.
- if i add `name = name.replace(filter, '');` then the script doesn't work.

#### My questions:

1 - how to properly include a `single quote` in the regex?

2 - how to properly include `double quotes` as well?

#### - Update

i tested my same regular expression in `asp.net` using `RegularExpressionValidator` and it's working fine because i can wrap it with double quotes i think:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="name is not valid" validationgroup="validationgroup1" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,50}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but in `JavaScript` i can't wrap the regex in double quotes. So there must be some way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

```
var filter = /^[\w'".\s]{1,50}$/
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2LVAh/)

You can use `\w` to represent word characters like `a-zA-Z0-9` and `^` marks the start and `$` marks the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you Arun for the info about `\w` `^` and `$` but I'm afraid the solution didn't work.

Comment: yes, the script doesn't throw an alert at all. i tried your solution `var filter = /^[\w'".\s]{1,50}$/` and this too `var filter = /^[\wa-zA-Z'.\s]{1,50}$/;`

Comment: is there any error in the browser console? are you sure the `checkname()` method is getting called

Comment: yes sure the function works properly and it is called because i tried other regex that don't contain a single quote and they work such as a regex for email but when there is a single quote then there are problems. So my guess the problem is with the regular expression.

Comment: single quote is valid or invalid

Comment: I've created a test file at https://gist.github.com/arunpjohny/5081202 can you check it

Comment: In my test cases `dd'$` gives the alert message

Comment: actually your solution might be working, i tested it with inputs that should throw an alert:
`dd'$` this works in both FF and IE as an alert is thrown,
`dd'1` this doesn't work in FF at all but does in IE,
`123` this too doesn't work in FF at all but does in IE.
so your solution doesn't seem to work with numbers in FF at all i'm afraid. that is weird. any hint?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
var filter = /[a-zA-Z\"']{1,50}/;
```

Comment: Special characters that have no special meaning inside `[]` don't need to be escaped, plus that isn't valid JS...

Comment: with escaping the quotes, if i have input example `100name` the regex works as the script throws the alert. but with `name100` the regex doesn't work. Plus it doesn't work at all without wrapping it with forward slashes. Anyway thank you ArthasNed_StarkGimli.

Comment: no problem. Anyway id go with Aruns answer as its the correct one

Comment: @elclanrs thank you for your comment but I'm afraid I'm not sure which is you mean is not valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can try your filter as below with hexadecimal or escape with backslash \

```
var filter = /[a-zA-Z\x22\x27]{1,50}/;
```

or

```
var filter = /[a-zA-Z\"\']{1,50}/;
```

In hexdecimal, `"` is `\x22` and `'` is `\x27`

This should work.